# Does tinyint allow decimals mysql/mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

If not, what should be used instead?

I'm surprised I havent found a question on stack about this.

Comment: No.  Integers do not have decimal points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decimals, you can use Decimal data type or Double datatype.

However you might be tempted to use FLOAT data type which can cause problems in some scenarios

If you are storing a number 13.59, in case of FLOAT data type, it will be first converted to Binary digits and then stored. While retrieving the data, binary will be converted to decimal and then displayed. But the problem here is 13.59 cannot be described with finite number of binary digits.

Binary of 13.59 will be 1101.1001011...... which when retrieved back will be 13.59000015258789...

So, if you compare this value with 13.59 in any of your queries, you will get wrong results.

Decimal and Double won't cause this problem as they don't store binary.

Best suggestion is to avoid Float

Comment: You start with good advice but half of it is incorrect. 
 `DOUBLE` has exactly the same problem as `FLOAT`.  Both are for storing values that are approximate, subject to the limitations of floating point number storage (not a limitation specific to MySQL):   *["The `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` types represent approximate numeric data values. MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)*  `DECIMAL` should *always* be the choice except when scale is more important than precision.